# MATCH_RECOGNIZE to find events that do not end with certain pattern

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, match-recognize

I have the transaction audit history as following. All audits start with a `INIT` and **may** have a `REVERSAL` and a `MODIFICATION`. I need to find all the audits with `INIT` -> `REVERSAL` but no `MODIFICATION`

| TRANSACTION_ID | ACTION | AMOUNT | AUDIT_TS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | INIT | 14 | 2022-07-10 14:49:17 |
| 111 | INIT | 10 | 2022-07-10 14:03:09 |
| 111 | REVERSAL | 10 | 2022-07-10 14:24:10 |
| 111 | MODIFICATION | 8 | 2022-07-10 14:49:11 |
| 222 | INIT | 12 | 2022-07-10 14:07:12 |
| 222 | REVERSAL | 12 | 2022-07-10 14:24:12 |
| 222 | MODIFICATION | 9 | 2022-07-10 14:43:13 |
| 333 | REVERSAL | 15 | 2022-07-10 14:26:14 |
| 333 | MODIFICATION | 14 | 2022-07-10 14:43:15 |
| 444 | INIT | 14 | 2022-07-10 14:42:16 |
| 555 | INIT | 5 | 2022-07-10 14:08:18 |
| 555 | REVERSAL | 5 | 2022-07-10 14:26:19 |

I tried using the Regex End Anchor ($) as following, but it also returns the audits that end with `MODIFICATION`:

```
select 
 *
from audit_table
match_recognize(
    partition by transaction_id
    order by audit_ts
    ALL ROWS PER MATCH
    PATTERN (INIT REVERSAL$)
    DEFINE
          INIT as iff(ACTION='INIT',TRUE,FALSE),
          REVERSAL as iff(ACTION='REVERSAL',TRUE,FALSE),
          MODIFICATION as iff(ACTION='MODIFICATION',TRUE,FALSE)
);
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern needs to be altered using [quantifiers](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/match_recognize.html#define-defining-symbols) `^INIT{1} REVERSAL{1}$`:

```
select  *
from audit_table
match_recognize(
    partition by transaction_id
    order by audit_ts
    ALL ROWS PER MATCH
    PATTERN (^INIT{1} REVERSAL{1}$)
    DEFINE
         INIT as ACTION='INIT',
         REVERSAL as ACTION='REVERSAL',
         MODIFICATION as ACTION='MODIFICATION'
)
ORDER BY transaction_id, audit_ts;
```

Snowflake supports boolean data type natively so:

```
INIT as iff(ACTION='INIT',TRUE,FALSE),
<=>
INIT as ACTION='INIT',
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another why to think about this, is to just write the logic you want:

```
with data(TRANSACTION_ID,   ACTION, AMOUNT, AUDIT_TS) as (
    select 
        column1, column2, column3, try_to_timestamp(column4) 
    from values
    (0      ,'INIT',    14, '2022-07-10 14:49:17'),
    (111    ,'INIT',    10, '2022-07-10 14:03:09'),
    (111    ,'REVERSAL',    10, '2022-07-10 14:24:10'),
    (111    ,'MODIFICATION',    8,  '2022-07-10 14:49:11'),
    (222    ,'INIT',    12, '2022-07-10 14:07:12'),
    (222    ,'REVERSAL',    12, '2022-07-10 14:24:12'),
    (222    ,'MODIFICATION',    9,  '2022-07-10 14:43:13'),
    (333    ,'REVERSAL',    15, '2022-07-10 14:26:14'),
    (333    ,'MODIFICATION',    14, '2022-07-10 14:43:15'),
    (444    ,'INIT',    14, '2022-07-10 14:42:16'),
    (555    ,'INIT',    5,  '2022-07-10 14:08:18'),
    (555    ,'REVERSAL',    5,  '2022-07-10 14:26:19')
)
select
    *
    ,first_value(ACTION) over(partition by TRANSACTION_ID order by AUDIT_TS) = 'INIT' as l1
    ,last_value(ACTION) over(partition by TRANSACTION_ID order by AUDIT_TS) = 'REVERSAL' as l2
    ,count(ACTION) over(partition by TRANSACTION_ID) = 2 as l3
    ,l1 and l2 and l3 logic_you_want
from data
order by 1,4;
```

| TRANSACTION_ID | ACTION | AMOUNT | AUDIT_TS | L1 | L2 | L3 | LOGIC_YOU_WANT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | INIT | 14 | 2022-07-10 14:49:17.000 | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| 111 | INIT | 10 | 2022-07-10 14:03:09.000 | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| 111 | REVERSAL | 10 | 2022-07-10 14:24:10.000 | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| 111 | MODIFICATION | 8 | 2022-07-10 14:49:11.000 | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| 222 | INIT | 12 | 2022-07-10 14:07:12.000 | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| 222 | REVERSAL | 12 | 2022-07-10 14:24:12.000 | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| 222 | MODIFICATION | 9 | 2022-07-10 14:43:13.000 | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| 333 | REVERSAL | 15 | 2022-07-10 14:26:14.000 | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE |
| 333 | MODIFICATION | 14 | 2022-07-10 14:43:15.000 | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE |
| 444 | INIT | 14 | 2022-07-10 14:42:16.000 | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| 555 | INIT | 5 | 2022-07-10 14:08:18.000 | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE |
| 555 | REVERSAL | 5 | 2022-07-10 14:26:19.000 | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE |

thus:

```
select
    *
from data
qualify first_value(ACTION) over(partition by TRANSACTION_ID order by AUDIT_TS) = 'INIT' 
    and last_value(ACTION) over(partition by TRANSACTION_ID order by AUDIT_TS) = 'REVERSAL'
    and count(ACTION) over(partition by TRANSACTION_ID) = 2
order by 1,4;
```

gives:

| TRANSACTION_ID | ACTION | AMOUNT | AUDIT_TS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 555 | INIT | 5 | 2022-07-10 14:08:18.000 |
| 555 | REVERSAL | 5 | 2022-07-10 14:26:19.000 |